# Is it possible to define a perverse $t$-structure for a certain triangulated category of sheaves of spectra?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, soft-question

The perverse t-structure for the derived category of complexes of sheaves is certainly a mighty tool for studying cohomology. My question is: does there exist any homotopy-theoretic analogue for it (probably, on some stable homotopy category of sheaves of spectra)?

Comment: Lurie gives a definition of a t-structure for stable $\infty$-categories in _Higher Algebra_, but I don't know how you would define the "support conditions" for sheaves of spectra

Comment: So, Lurie didn't define anything like this?

Comment: I think that the question is not whether $t$-structures can be defined for enhancements of triangulated categories (such as $\infty$-categories), but whether perverse $t$-structures can be defined for ordinary triangulated categories of purely topological origin. Mikhail, am I right?

Comment: Yes; I am not very much interested in enhancements of any sort. Yet I am not sure that one could call (some) triangulated category of etale sheaves of spectra a category of purely topological origin.:)

Comment: I meant it cannot be embedded in the homotopy category of an additive category (the existence of such an embedding is often taken as a definition of algebraic triangulated category).

Comment: Yes; I believe that homotopy groups cannot be studied by means of algebraic triangulated categories.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Did you ever figure this out? If so please come back and answer your question!